# filter array of objects on click by 'last month' and 'last week' using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, momentjs, angular-moment

I have a dateCreated as 2015-12-11T11:12:14.635Z coming from database for every object in an array

I want to filter that array for the last week and last month

Problem is if today is the 19th March, i was to search from the 11th to the 18th for the last 7 days and that seems to search for the last 7 days by calculating 24 hours * 7 by my searches need to start from 00:00:01 each day.

now i  1st want to calculate last week first.. based on current date using moment.js and then i will convert it to the above format so that i can filter data

Basically, I want to calculate last week based on current timestamp.

Comment: After you calculated the first and last day of the week, use the date [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method change the time, e.g.,  fistDay.setHours(0,0,0); lastDay.setHours(23,59,59);  Then your filter spans the entire week period. Beware that timezone can cause problems.   Also see: [setUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours)

Comment: last week means previous week  Monday - Sunday ? or last 7 days?

Comment: it`s not clear what you are looking for: 1- just last week and month js date; 2-also an help on filtering the object (this is a js one or a server side filter one)

Answer (score 6):

the dates should be:

```
var last7DayStart = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1,'week');
var lastMonthThisDay = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1,'month');
var yesterdayEndOfRange =  moment().endOf('day').subtract(1,'day');
```

then if it is a javascript filter i would use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and do:

```
var javascriptArrayOfObjectsWithDates = [
          { date : '2015-12-11T11:12:14.635Z', anotherProperty: 0 },
          { date : moment().subtract(1, 'day' ).format(), testThis: 'works!'}
        ];

var filteredObjects = _.filter(javascriptArrayOfObjectsWithDates,     
                       function(each){ 
                          return moment(each.date)
                            .isBetween(last7DayStart, yesterdayEndOfRange) ;
                       });
```

Answer (score 3):

I did like this.. and its working for me..

> ```
> _this.lastWeek = function () {
>   var result = moment().subtract(7,'days').hours(0);   
>   return result._d;
> };
>
> _this.lastMonth = function () {
>   var result = moment().subtract(30,'days').hours(0);   
>   return result._d;
> };
> ```

then i filtered my array using underscoreJS.. (YOU CAN USE loadash also)..

> ```
> _this.thisWeekData = _.filter(_this.inbox, function(inbox) {
>     return (moment(inbox.createdAt) > _this.lastWeek());
> });
>
> _this.lastWeekData = _.filter(_this.inbox, function(inbox) {
>     return ((moment(inbox.createdAt) < _this.lastWeek()) && (moment(inbox.createdAt) > _this.lastMonth()));
> });
>
> _this.lastMonthData = _.filter(_this.inbox, function(inbox) {
>     return (moment(inbox.createdAt) < _this.lastMonth());
> });
> ```

if you dont want to do all this stuff in your controller then there is angular library for variety of filters.. you can directly use it in html.. "**Angular-filter**"

[angular-filter library link is here](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Thankyou guys for all your support..

Comment: same comment as for the other answer: **.hours(0)** is leaving minutes and seconds, therefore some result may fall in those (e.g. you could have them in lastmontdata but they belong to last week or they fall in lastweekdata but they are 59 minute and 59 seconds in the day after or 6 days and 23 hours and 1 sec ago

Comment: it looks as you merged the two answers into one and adapted those to your code...the right process is to mark one as correct if it is (and one can conclude that mine looks so from your own...that`s elementar)

Answer (score 1):

this should get you to the point in time 7 days ago at 00:00:00

`var time7daysAgo = moment().subtract(7,'days').startOf('day');`

`var time30daysAgo = moment().subtract(30,'days').startOf('day');`

after that you just format to whatever you like. Say to a milisecond unix timestamp:

`var time7daysAgoMiliseconds = time7daysAgo.format('x');`

comparison on numbers is quite handy after this point.

Comment: this is setting only the hour to 0 the minutes and second stays

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my way of filtering by
>
> 1. Today
> 2. Last 7 Days (Last Week, inclusive)
> 3. Last 30 days (Last Month, inclusive)

```
const today = moment();
const lastSevenDays = moment().subtract(7, 'days');
const lastThirtyDays = moment().subtract(30, 'days');

const FILTER_MAP = {
  All: () => true,
  Today: task => task.timestamp.isBetween(today, today, 'day', '[]'), // [] means inclusive
  Week: task => task.timestamp.isBetween(lastSevenDays, today, 'day', '[]'),
  Month: task => task.timestamp.isBetween(lastThirtyDays, today, 'day', '[]'),
};

const DATA = [
  { id: "0", name: "Eat", timestamp: moment().subtract(6, 'days') },
  { id: "1", name: "Sleep", timestamp: moment() },
  { id: "2", name: "Pawn", timestamp: moment().subtract(28, 'days') },
  { id: "3", name: "Repeat", timestamp: moment().add(1, 'days') } //testing purpose + 1 day
];
```